# Font size bug in android chrome browser

Tags: android, html, css

I have a trouble of html+css for android phone (my environment is Nexus 5, Chrome beta).

Let's see this css:

```
<style type="text/css"><!--
div.sample {
  margin: 12px 2px 12px 2px;
}
div.sample span {
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  border: 3px solid #f00;
  background-color: #fcc;
}
--></style>
```

And the body part (html):

```
<div class="sample"><span>SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE</span></div>
<div class="sample"><span><a>SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE</a></span></div>
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
```

The "test test ..." part is added to activate the "font boosting" of webkit.

The problem is that we expect the first div (SAMPLE...) looks similar as the second div (SAMPLE...), however, it looks like this:

[image: Android chrome view]

In the second div case, the span does not expand to fit its element (SAMPLE...).

If we add some text outside the a tag, the both div looks as the same.

```
<div class="sample"><span>SAMPLE<a>SAMPLE SAMPLE SAMPLE</a></span></div>
```

Do you know what the problem is?  How can I solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: So, do you need first div.sample look like second div.sample? reason I ask is, the second one looks actually broken to me, because it's background span doesn't wrap its whole content.

Comment: No, I want the second div.sample to look like the first div.sample. The second one is bad to me.

Comment: One more thing - is it all of your css? What Android version is it? Try to set `.sample span a { display: inline-block }`or `.sample span a { display: block }`

Comment: I used desktop google chrome to identify the problem, but I couldn't. My Android is 5.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `display` property of you `div.sample span` to `inline-block`.
This will enable wrapping whole of your content.
I reproduced your problem here - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctL2yqw0/)

Setting up

```
div.sample span {
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: 3px solid #f00;
    background-color: #fcc;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

removes the problem - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctL2yqw0/1/).
I would suspect this is due to the default size of font on link element, which is probably greater than font-size of span element.

Comment: Great! `display:inline-block;` really solved my problem. Thanks!